# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/VideoCall'

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, material-ui

I can't install whether I use --force or something else

```js
import { Container, MenuItem, Select, InputLabel } from '@material-ui/core';
```

I want to install and resolve these errors

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core'
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Event'
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/VideoCall'

Comment: you should follow the documentation of mui to install properly the package https://mui.com/material-ui/migration/migration-v4/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using npm run the below command.

`npm install @material-ui/core@^4.11.2 react@^17.0.0`

If you are using yarn run the below command.

`yarn upgrade @material-ui/core@^4.11.2 react@^17.0.0`

Comment: but it still shows error . I cant download material.ui